# What is the resistance of this structure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, material-science

A device is made of a material with resistivity ρ and has a structure as shown in the below picture. What is the resistance of this structure?

[image]

In my opinion, it is equal to a single block of material with a cross-sectional area of ​​10x10 mm2 and a length of 5 mm.

Is it right?
If wrong, what should I think? Please help explain.

Comment: If accuracy is required, this 'homework' question can only be solved by advanced computation. The resistance depends on where the charges are injected. A first estimate can be made based on ignoring the protrusions and approximate by a 5x3x10 block. This is why the author chose a thickness of only 3 mm, which however is not represented to scale in the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true for very thin plates.

If the block dimensions are of comparable lengths, the outer half plate has a linear potential along its vertical boundary to its inner half.

It is generating a current of parabolic shape into the volume.

Shifting the plate results in a  growth of current from zero to its maximum.

The growth of current is quadratic by the product of two factors: linear in contact area, inverse linear by shortening the current paths between two opposite points on the contact areas.

Since these questions are really hard to calculate, see a graphics solution by Mathematica

```
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], Opacity[0.3], 
           Blue, Rectangle[{0, 2.5}, {10, 7.5}],
         Green, Rectangle[{6, -2.5}, {16, 2.5}],
          Red, Rectangle[{0, -7.5}, {10, -2.5}]}]
```

[image: Three layers]

```
     region = RegionUnion[
        Rectangle[{0, 2.5}, {10, 7.5}],
        Rectangle[{6, -2.5}, {16, 2.5}],
        Rectangle[{0, -7.5}, {10, -2.5}]];

     U[x_, y_] = 
    NDSolveValue[
       {Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
        \[Phi][x, 7.5] ==1, \[Phi][x, -7.5] == 0},
        \[Phi][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region ];
     J[x_,y_]=Grad[soln[x, y], {x, y}];

    cplU = ContourPlot[soln[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region];
    cplJ = VectorPlot[j[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region];
    Show[{cplU, cplJ}]
```

[image: Potential and Current]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer! What is the resulting resistance value for this particular choice of current injection?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered my question. 
@Roland F

This answer shows the current flow. The picture answered my curiosity about how the current would flow. Will current flow through every point in the material? (especially the middle plate)

From this answer, I want to learn how to use Mathematica.
As far as I can see from the code, it's probably just a piece of code that has been cut out from the complete one. Is it possible to request the full code for further study? Thank you.